# Loop through ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I'm trying to loop through an `ArrayList` an get the current value of the loop instance.

```
public ArrayList<Double> getCurrent(double x) {

    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

    list.add(x);

    ArrayList<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); 

    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        sum += list.get(i);
        list1.add(sum);
    }

    return list1;

}
```

Here are my JSP file. Note the loop goes through my `ArrayList` history, and the values I want to parse into the new `ArrayList` from the method `getCurrent(double x)` takes `ret`.

```
<% for (history his : history) {


    double ret = his.getRet();
    double dep = his.getDeposit();
    String res = his.getRes();

    if (res.equals("Loss")) {
        ret = -dep;
         }

 %>

<h1><%=his.getCurrent(ret) %></h1>

<%} %>
```

This gives my an `ArrayList` which consist of the correct values, but NOT added with the previous values. The `ArrayList` now shows: `[30.0, -5.0, 20.0]` which is correct values. However, I want it to display: `[30, 25, 45]` so the values are added together with all previous values.

Comment: If you are totally relying on integer values, then I will recommend using a list of an int instead of float. I'm adding my answer bellow, hope this would help

Comment: Thank you. I'm not relying on integer values. I look forward to see you answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not quite getting your method. Why are you adding a single value to a list just to iterate over that list and add the value to sum? I suppose that's not what you want so my guess is that (re)defining `list` in your method is your problem. `ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>(); ` should most likely be somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is to pass the double values to this function and then the function will return the list with the calculated values.

According to your code whenever the function is invoked a `new Arraylist is declared every time`. Thus there are **no previous values**, there. If you want the output to be like what you have mentioned then `declare the list outside the function`. Once it is outside there is no need to declared it again and again. It will retain all the previous values and when you will do your calculation it will give you your expected output.

Comment: Thank you. Hmm I've tried declaring the list outside the function, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: @egx you should show what you did there since you probably did it wrong (remember: declaring the list outside the method won't help much if the method shadows it, i.e. creates another variable with the same name, or if it belongs to some object/method that also just "lives" for the duration of that single call).

Comment: can you please post your whole code. It would help a lot in fixing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to get some but your declared variable is not final. Every function call will reset its value and you will not be able to get the required results. Furthermore, the statement:

> ```
>     sum += list.get(i);
> ```

is not as much appropriate to all compilers and IDE's and this can cause runtime error and may contain garbage if not properly handled. I prefer using this modified code.

```js
    Final double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + list.get(i);
        list1.add(sum);
    }
```

Comment: Care to explain why `sum = sum + list.get(i);` is better than `sum += list.get(i);`? It's basically the same operation (both operands have the same type after auto unboxing which will happen in both statements).